# Where do I add a new development url to symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get up to speed with Symfony as quickly as possible but there is one thing that is driving me crazy!

I've set up a virtual host on my machine for development at `myproject.dev`.

However it doesn't load in the dev environment, it loads in production so all the twig view templates are getting cached, I can't see the debug toolbar.. etc etc.

Please can someone put me how to add `myproject.dev` to the dev url's?

--

Edit: Actually, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` still resolves to `127.0.0.1` so it should be loading the dev environment right? But it's not. `$this->getEnvironment();` resolves to `prod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `.htaccess` file with rewrite rule for dev-env. For example it can look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} \.dev$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then it will load your dev site in dev-environment only when site name has `.dev` suffix.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'd just got as far as realising the app.php or app_dev.php controller is targeted from the .htaccess. This makes perfect sense then so thanks again!!